# Stopping Account Sharing

Tags: php, user-accounts

I am trying to figure out a way to stop account sharing on a site that requires a login. To solve this I would want to base it on an individuals machine or ip.  I know I could base this on a cookies, which could possible be deleted or an ip which could possibly be dynamic.  Is there something that I am not thinking of?  As of now I am thinking I would have to base it on a cookie that can only be rewritten so often with an ip.

Is this the only way to handle it or can someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: Do you *really* want to limit each user to *only* be allowed to log in from a single machine?..

Comment: @Demian Brecht: Each user on a single machine _at a given time_ is not necessarily a bad thing.  (You let userslogin from wherever they wish to be be, but then for the duration of a session they cannot login from somewhere else)

Comment: Looking like I could possibly do this by getting the users MAC address but I am not sure if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would spend time looking into a system detecting account sharing instead of preventing. Not only do you not harm your average user logging in on a few locations, but it's also less time consuming and let's you be able to take more accurate action.

You can use your login / visit log for detection. More then one login in 5 minutes with distinct ip(s), the ip(s) used to login are from broad ISP's etc. etc.

Comment: After looking more into this I think this is the way I am going to have to go.  I will just log there IP and only allow 3 different ip's  every 24hours.  This is for a subscription based service so the client doesn't want users to be able to just give out there username and password.

Answer (score 0):

Well, don't hobble your site without considering the consequences. The same person could be logging in from work, school, ips can change because of dynamic addressing, etc...

You could force each id to be logged in from a unique location (e.g. record each login in a table where certain fields comprise a unique key, and look for insertion exceptions).  A login from a new location while the old location has been recently active could be set either to (a) fail at the new location, or (b) cause a failure at the old location, (c) inform the alternate location, (d) log somewhere.  Also, providing a table of where you've logged in from, shown to the user in fine print, together with a blurb on the policy might aid in compliance among "honest" people.